# Radio buttons are not showing check onclick in list

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, radio-button

I have been trying from many days on this code, but have not got the results yet. I have put radio buttons in list having same names. When i trying to click on the button it is not showing check sign. Here is the whole code

```
<form>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active choice-option">
            <a href="#account" value='1' data-toggle="tab">This is a General Inquiry or you need Assistance
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                    <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" value='1' checked>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="choice-option">
            <a href="#company" data-toggle="tab">You have a Technical Issue and need to open a ticket
                <span class="pull-right">   
                    <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                    <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" value='1' >
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "check sign". You code works just as normal as anythign else

Comment: Actually i'm storing the data via hidden form in DB. But if i'm gonna click these radio fields they don't show any radio check. Previously i was trying with the yii2 html helpers radios. I got the same results there too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give id to radio button and put label tag for text.

Try below code.

```
<form>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active choice-option">
            <a href="#account" value='1' data-toggle="tab"><label for="radio1">This is a General Inquiry or you need Assistance</label>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                    <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" value='1' id="radio1" checked>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="choice-option">
            <a href="#company" data-toggle="tab"><label for="radio2">You have a Technical Issue and need to open a ticket</label>
                <span class="pull-right">   
                    <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                    <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" id="radio2" value='1' >
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your radiobuttons are inside of anchor tag

```
<form>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active choice-option">
        <a href="#account" value='1' data-toggle="tab">This is a General Inquiry or you need Assistance</a>
            <span class="pull-right">
                <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" value='1' checked>
            </span>

    </li>
    <li class="choice-option">
        <a href="#company" data-toggle="tab">You have a Technical Issue and need to open a ticket</a>
            <span class="pull-right">   
                <!--?= Html::radio('type', true); ?-->
                <input type="radio" name="type" class="radio_showed" value='1' >
            </span>

    </li>
</ul>
```

In this case ,radio buttons are working,but it affects your styles